# Unit test method which deletes the files from a folder

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

we have a method which takes the folder name and number of days as a parameter.

```
    public void Delete(string folder, int days)
    {
        var files = Directory.GetFiles(folder);

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            var fi = new FileInfo(file);
            var fiCreationTime = fi.CreationTime;
            var deleteOlderThan= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-days);

            if (fiCreationTime >= deleteOlderThan) continue;
                fi.Delete();
        }
    }
```

What is the best way to unit test such methods in c#

Answer (score 2):

Actually you cannot unit test your method, because it depends on external APIs (*FileSystem, DateTime*).

So what you should do is separate logic and integration with external sources, it might look like this:

```
public class MyFileInfo
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreationTime { get; set; }
}

public interface IDateTimeProvider
{
    DateTime GetCurrentTime();
}

public interface IMyFileSystemService
{
    IEnumerable<MyFileInfo> GetFileInfos(string folder);

    void DeleteFile(MyFileInfo myFileInfo);
}

public class MyService
{
    private readonly IMyFileSystemService _myFileSystemService;
    private readonly IDateTimeProvider _dateTimeProvider;

    public MyService(IMyFileSystemService myFileSystemService, IDateTimeProvider dateTimeProvider)
    {
        _myFileSystemService = myFileSystemService;
        _dateTimeProvider = dateTimeProvider;
    }

    public void Delete(string folder, int days)
    {
        var files = _myFileSystemService.GetFileInfos(folder);

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            var deleteOlderThan = _dateTimeProvider.GetCurrentTime().AddDays(-days);

            if (file.CreationTime >= deleteOlderThan) continue;
            _myFileSystemService.DeleteFile(file);
        }
    }
}
```

I think implementation of interfaces `IDateTimeProvider` and `IMyFileSystemService` should not  be an issue.

Now you can write clean unit tests for `MyService.Delete`

Comment: _"you cannot unit test your method, because it depends on external APIs...DateTime"_ - that rules out 100% of .NET apps with their dependence on `AppDomain` - something that can't be undone

Comment: @User453465436754 I'm not really sure what AppDomain has to do with this. The statement made by Uriil is correct - the code *as is* cannot be unit tested because it has external dependencies on things that can't easily be controlled.

Comment: @mason If you don't understand the relevance of `AppDomain`, then how can you be sure as to your assertion?  Please stop trolling

Comment: @User453465436754 I'm not trolling - I'm asking you to clarify what AppDomain has to do with this, because I believe it has nothing to do with this.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is to use static helper classes

```
public static class FileEx
{
    public static Func<string, IEnumerable<string>> EnumerateFiles { set; get; }
       = Directory.EnumerateFiles;
}
```

and then only use the helper classes:

```
var files = FileEx.EnumerateFiles(...);
```

This way you can change the method in your unit tests.

```
[Test]
public void Test()
{
    FileEx.EnumerateFiles = (_) => new [] { "file1", "file2" };

    // your test here

    // Reset the method:
    FileEx.EnumerateFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles;
}
```

This works for most static helper methods and is way easier refactoring every class so it can be injected.

### Downsides

- you will lose function overloading.
- will only work for static classes (in your example it won't work for FileInfo).

### Upsides

- really easy
- easy to implement
- easy to change while testing
- easy to use

### Update to remarks in the comments:

It is viable to replace system methods as `Directory.EnumerateFiles` in your unit tests. 
Because you are testing your `Delete` method and one can assume that Microsoft has tested the framework code. Therefore the only thing the unit test must prove is that the `Delete` method has to correct output and side effects.

Comment: @User453465436754 what do you mean by AUT? To use it you just have to replace `Directory` with `FileEx`

Comment: You have to change the production code to use `FileEx` instead of `Directory`.

Comment: @User453465436754 not at all. Injecting a file service means refactoring the complete method. For the solution given above you only need to change the calls to static system methods. This solution has a much smaller footprint than injecting the services.

Answer (score 1):

The 100% solution is that lot of this has to be injected in because it either has sideeffects or is non-determenistic:

```
1) Directory.GetFiles
2) new FileInfo(file)
3) fi.CreationTime
4) DateTime.Now.AddDays
5) fi.Delete
```

So you inject e.g. a datetimeservice in that in production that returns datetime, and in test where it always returns some fixed date. And use a mocking framework to check that sometimes the delete method is called, and other times it isn't called.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to unit test the method you have shown it would be difficult in the way it is currently written, but we could mock the `File` class and pass an interface for it to use:

```
public class FileDeleter
{

    private readonly IFileOperator _fileOperator;

    public FileDeleter(IFileOperator fileOperator)
    {
        _fileOperator= fileOperator
    }

    public void Delete(string folder, int days)
    {
        var files = _fileClass.GetFiles(folder);

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            var fi = _fileClass.GetFileInfo(file);
            var fiCreationTime = fi.CreationTime;
            var deleteOlderThan= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-days);

            if (fiCreationTime >= deleteOlderThan)
                continue;
            fi.Delete();
        }
    }
}

public interface IFileClass 
{
    IEnumerable<string> GetFiles(string path);
    IFileInfo GetFileInfo(string filePath);
}

public interface IFileInfo 
{
    DateTime CreationTime { get; }
    void Delete();
}
```

After that, simply mock the two classes with a library like: https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart

and write your unit tests testing whatever logic is required.

EDIT: As others have pointed out, datetime.now might be a good thing to mock too, but can be done in that same way.

Comment: You might not be aware, a [good library for abstracting out System.IO is already available](https://github.com/tathamoddie/System.IO.Abstractions) - no need to create your own interfaces to do so. Implementations are even provided that allow you to build a virtual system is even provided.

Answer (score 0):

The perfect solution for your code would create an interface which has methods for all files operation and then mock those methods

but you can also create virtual methods for those file operation in your sample class and mock that method in a unit test

Following is code implementation of your actual code

```
public class Sample
{
    public void Delete(string folder, int days)
    {
        var files = GetFiles(folder);

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            var fi = GetFileInfo(file);
            var fiCreationTime = fi.CreationTime;
            var deleteOlderThan = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-days);

            if (fiCreationTime >= deleteOlderThan) continue;
            DeleteFile(fi);
        }
    }

    public virtual void DeleteFile(FileInfo f)
    {
        f.Delete();
    }

    public virtual string[] GetFiles(string path)
    {
        return Directory.GetFiles(path);
    }

    public virtual FileInfo GetFileInfo(string file)
    {
        return new FileInfo(file);
    }
}
```

And following is your unit test class

```
public class NUnitTest
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        private Mock<Sample> _sample;
        private FileInfo _fileInfo;
        [SetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {
            _sample = new Mock<Sample>();

        }

        [Test]
        public void File_Should_Not_Delete()
        {
            _fileInfo = new FileInfo("file");
            _fileInfo.Create();

            _sample.Setup(x => x.GetFiles(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(() => new[] {"file1"});
            _sample.Setup(x => x.GetFileInfo(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(() => _fileInfo);
            _sample.Setup(x => x.DeleteFile(It.IsAny<FileInfo>())).Verifiable();
            _sample.Object.Delete("file1",2);

            _sample.Verify(x => x.DeleteFile(It.IsAny<FileInfo>()), Times.Never);

        }

        [Test]
        public void File_Should_Delete()
        {
            _fileInfo = new FileInfo("file1");
            _fileInfo.Create();

            _sample.Setup(x => x.GetFiles(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(() => new[] { "file1" });
            _sample.Setup(x => x.GetFileInfo(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(() => _fileInfo);
            _sample.Setup(x => x.DeleteFile(It.IsAny<FileInfo>())).Verifiable();
            _sample.Object.Delete("file1", -2);

            _sample.Verify(x => x.DeleteFile(It.IsAny<FileInfo>()), Times.Once);

        }
    }
}
```

I know this is not good design practice but I just want to showcase you a different way of doing unit testing using a virtual method.

Bestway is to create an interface and mock those interface method which I created as a virtual