# unit test bash script function which deletes files older than certain number of days

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unit-testing, bats-core

I don't have much experience with bash/shell scripting and just recently started writing some bash scripts with unit tests using Bats framework or libraries. Currently writing a script which needs to delete the files older than certain number of days. Below is the function.

```
function deleteFilesOlderThan() {
 echo "Deleting files older than $1 days"
 eval "find ./test-files -mtime +$1 -exec rm {} \;"
}
```

Is it possible to unit test the above function as it has complex command? If it is not possible can we rewrite the above function some other way so that it is unit testable. Please advise.

Comment: not bash but the principles seem the same: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50929407/10971581

Comment: is the `eval` just for demonstration? seems unnecessary unless `$1` is supposed to contain something complicated you are trying to expand (which doesn't seem to be the case)

Comment: You can use `touch -d` to set the date - time on files against which you can run your tests.  See https://askubuntu.com/questions/62492/how-can-i-change-the-date-modified-created-of-a-file.  And remove that `eval`, you want to try never to use `eval`.  See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048

Comment: It might be useful at this point to mention https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ as a place to get help on how to improve your code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my perspective, you are asking three separate questions:

1. Is my code any good?
2. How do I write test in general for BASH
3. How do I test this specific code?

As that sounds more like a request for code review, it might be better suited to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ but I'll answer here anyway...

The command isn't really that complex. But even if it were, you'd be testing the side-effect of the code, not the code itself. So complexity in the code doesn't even really matter...

Anyway, a test would look something like this:

```sh
@test "deleteFilesOlderThan deletes files" {
  # Arrange
  touch -t 123412312345 ./test-files/test.txt

  # Act
  deleteFilesOlderThan 1000

  # Assert
  [ ! -f ./test-files/test.txt ]
}
```

You could add more tests, for instance checking the output using `assert_output`, and checking that *newer* files do *not* get deleted.

The code *can* be tested without being rewritten but there are some potential problems in the code:

- As state in the comments, the `eval` is not really needed. The `find` command can run fine as-is, without being wrapped in an `eval`.
- There are *no* checks. None. At all. You might want to *at least* check that `$1` is actually provided. You *could* also check whether it is an integer or not.
- You could check that `test-files` actually exists
- The `test-files` directory is hard-coded. I would make that a parameter of the function. That way it can be provided with a different path for the test than that used for real.

These changes could look something like this:

```sh
function deleteFilesOlderThan() {
  local days="${1:?Two parameters required: <days> <path>}"
  local path="${2:?Two parameters required: <days> <path>}"
  
  if [[ -n ${days} && ${days} = *[!0123456789]* ]]; then
    echo "ERROR: Given days '${days}' is not an integer" >&2
  elif [[ ! -d "${path}" ]]; then
    echo "ERROR: Given path '${path}' is not a directory" >&2  
  else
    echo "Deleting files older than ${1} days in ${path}"

    find "${path}" -mtime "+${1}" -exec rm {} \;
  fi
}
```

Of course, now that there is more code, there should also be more tests. I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.

---

If you are not already familiar with it, you might want to check out [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/). It will warn you if you write any code that might cause problems.

You might also want to look at `shfmt` (from the [mvdan.cc/sh](https://github.com/mvdan/sh) package) to formats shell script.

Comment: Hi @Potherca. Thank you very much for the detailed explanation with example.

Comment: You're very welcome! I've noticed that it can be hard for beginner or intermediate developers to find answers to _specific_ problems, so I always try to help answers those questions when I can.